# Issues with a Flutter plugin, after updating to iOS 17

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio

Building a Flutter project in Android Studio, after updating to iOS 17, it says me this error:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'Flutter'
/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_progress_hud_nsn-0.4.0/ios/Classes/ModalProgressHudNsnPlugin.swift:0:7


Encountered error while building for device.
```

The problem is in a plug-in that worked until yesterday, the modal_progress_hud_nsn.

Thanks!

I tried to solve this by doing `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, and `flutter build ios`, but it did not work.

Comment: No, for now I keep going with previous versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this section in your `podfile`.

- Replace the following code :

```
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      end
    end
```

- Replace with below code :

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end
```

I hope this solution might be work for you.

Comment: It worked! Thank you:)